# what do you call this effect and how do you implant it

Tags: css, google-web-designer

i found a cool css effect on css zen garden.what effect have he used to switch image on the maroon color section when we scroll.i have seen this effect on many web sites but doesn't know the proper name or technique.any help would be appreciated.

[link to csszendgarden](http://www.csszengarden.com/216/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique is called Parallex and can be implemented easily by marerializecss

Comment: Do you mean "parallax" with two 'l's? This doesn't really answer the question though, which was 'how to implement it'.

Answer (score 0):

The site has a download link for the CSS. Also, for future reference if you want to learn how a site does anything with CSS, just right click and Inspect Element.

Comment: i'm not looking for the code im looking what you call the effect